# Spring not showing logs for schema.sql

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am learning spring boot by working on a spring project and attempting to use h2 as an embedded database. Below are the details:
**Project Structure**:

[image]

**application.properties file contain:**

```
logging.level.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils=debug
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

The problem is spring boot doesn't show logs for queries inside `schema.sql` and `data.sql`.

**Logs for reference:**

```
INFO 19121 --- [           main] c.v.l.l.LearningSpringApplication        : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
INFO 19121 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
INFO 19121 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 10 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
INFO 19121 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
INFO 19121 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
INFO 19121 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.54]
INFO 19121 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
INFO 19121 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1534 ms
INFO 19121 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
INFO 19121 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
INFO 19121 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
INFO 19121 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.32.Final
INFO 19121 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
INFO 19121 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
INFO 19121 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
INFO 19121 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
WARN 19121 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
INFO 19121 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.w.s.WelcomePageHandlerMapping    : Adding welcome page: class path resource [static/index.html]
INFO 19121 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
INFO 19121 --- [           main] c.v.l.l.LearningSpringApplication        : Started LearningSpringApplication in 3.858 seconds (JVM running for 4.364)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use h2 inmemory db with spring-data-jpa, you can see all query in console when hibernate use query to db.

You can see query by add `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true` in application.properties.